# imageView doesn't show image from UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to programmatically use an image from UIImagePickerController in one view controller and have that be the imageView in another view controller. Here is the method from viewController A

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

 bandCropViewController *viewController = [[bandCropViewController alloc]init];
 viewController.imageOriginal = image;
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
 // Move to Crop View Controller
 [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}];
}
```

ViewController B looks like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 280)];
  [self.imageView setImage:imageOriginal];
  imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
  [self.view addSubview:imageView];
}
```

viewController B is showing the imageView frame in red as it should be. But the image is not carrying over.

Any thoughts as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you making ViewController B? Storyboard? Xib file? Code?

Comment: try self.imageOriginal, try to NSLog the image object in imagePicker delegate to see if you are getting a proper image. In imagePicker delegate try this too viewController.imageOriginal = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

Answer (score 0):

Highly recommend [this tutorial](http://blog.hanpo.tw/2012/01/uiimagepickercontroller-and-simple.html)

It should help you out. It looks like you are possibly doing some unnecessary things in

`- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{`